# Mapping kernel global variable to User space

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am trying to deliever a virtual address of global variable created in Kernel space into user space (linux).

The best way I found so far is to use remap_pfn_range() function, providing it with the physical address of my global variable, and return to the user space the mapped address.

I wander if there is a better way to do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to write to that memory from userspace or just get the location of the pointer?

Comment: I want to write to that memory area from user space

Comment: Well you'll probably want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9663366/3388817

Comment: Thank You it seems that there isn't a better way

Comment: this would assumably work, but not everything that works is necessarily a good idea.