# Programming a kernel module, so that I can serve?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wish someone could tell me the advantage of creating a module to the kernel because it can not see the difference with a normal executable. I know that depends on the task at hand but I could give an example?

Comment: Search for differences between user and kernel space to provide some clues. eg. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957630/302243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to building kernel modules depends on your needs.

For further instruction please read something like http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html

After that if you have some more detailed question regarding on how to create kernel modules feel free to come back ;)