# ARM Odroid xu3 wake up secondary cores

Tags: arm, odroid

I'm trying to wake up secondary cores on Odroid xu3.

I used bootloader(u-boot) that provieded by Hardkernel.

This bootloader take me to non-secure world. so my program is started from non-secure world automatically.

This is the codes that wake up secondsary cores.

```
dsb_sev();
writel((unsigned int) reset_for_debugging, 0x02073000);
```

dsb_sev(); is for dsb and sev instruction
dtb said 0x02073000 address is for sysrams for non-secure. and reset_for_debugging is a function that i secondary cores should run at first.

Is there anything that i should know more? or i have to check?

Comment: look at how the linux port does it for that chip/board

Comment: You should probably start by checking where to write the boot address, because I don't think it's [the _very_ beginning of the non-secure SRAM](https://github.com/hardkernel/u-boot/blob/odroidxu3-v2012.07/board/samsung/smdk5422/lowlevel_init.S#L243). Then you most likely have to poke the power controller to actually power the requisite cores on. (and no, unfortunately I don't know the relevant specifics, I just [once did the same thing with a different Odroid board](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20907141/3156750) and still vaguely remember the general Exynos 5 boot process).