# In reference to fibers, what is user space?

Tags: fiber, userspace

When people explain the difference between threads and fibers, they often refer to the fact that fibers are in "user space". What does "user space" mean?

Comment: Not kernel space. IOW, fibers don't run in ring 0.

Comment: All that tells me is that I need to learn a LOT more about OSs. Is there more you can give to make it clearer? I'll understand if you don't think so.

Comment: The first answer to [What are Ring 0 and Ring 3 in OS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18717016/62576) has some useful links.