# What does SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) represent?

Tags: linker, binaryfiles, ld, binutils, memory-layout

I'm learning about the layout of executable binaries. My end goal is to analyze a specific executable for things that could be refactored (in its source) to reduce the compiled output size.

I've been using https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/900.php and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/ as references for this initial learning.

From what I've learned, a linker script specifies the addresses where sections of compiled binaries are placed. E.g.

```
> ld --verbose | grep text
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
```

I think this means that the `text` segments of compiled binaries starts at memory address `0x400000` - true?

**What does that value, `0x400000`, represent?** I'm probably not understanding something properly, but surely that `0x400000` does not represent a physical memory location, does it? E.g. if I were to run two instances of my compiled `a.out` executable in parallel, they couldn't *both* simultaneously occupy the space at `0x400000`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x4000000 is not a *physical address* in the sense how your memory chips see it. This is a *virtual address* as it's seen from CPU's point of view.

Loader of your program will map a few pages of physical memory to VA 0x400000 and copy the contents of `text-segment` to it. And yes, another instance of your program could occupy the same physical and virtual block of memory for the `text-segment`, because text (code) is readable and executable but **not writeable**. Other segments (data, bss, stack, heap) may have identical VA but each will be mapped to their private **protected** physical block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

**What is 0x400000**

> I think this means that the text segments of compiled binaries starts at memory address 0x400000 - true?

No, this is well explained in the official documentation at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Builtin-Functions.html

> SEGMENT_START(segment, default)
>
> Return the base address of the named segment. If an explicit value has already been given for this segment (with a command-line ‘-T’ option) then that value will be returned otherwise the value will be default. At present, the ‘-T’ command-line option can only be used to set the base address for the “text”, “data”, and “bss” sections, but you can use SEGMENT_START with any segment name.

Therefore, `SEGMENT_START` is not setting the address, but rather it is returning it, and `0x4000000` in your case is just the default if that value was not deterministically set by some CLI mechanism mentioned in the documentation (e.g. `-Ttext=0x200` as mentioned in `man ld`)

**Physical vs virtual**

As you've said, doing things in physical addresses is very uncommon in userland, and would at the very least always require `sudo` as it would [break process separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems/44483439#44483439). Here is an example of userland doing physical address stuff for example: [How to access physical addresses from user space in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040303/how-to-access-physical-addresses-from-user-space-in-linux/45127890#45127890)

Therefore, when the kernel [loads an ELF binary with the `exec` syscalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861), all addresses are interpreted as virtual addresses.

Note however that this is just a matter of convention. For example, when I [give my Linux kernel ELF binary for QEMU to load into memory to start simulation](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/6bb20c0386936b57a707966cd484d6e951cb47ef#qemu-buildroot-setup-getting-started), or when a bootloader does that in a real system, the ELF addresses would then be treated as physical addresses since there is no page table available at that point.