# Details about Protection Ring system

Tags: x86, kernel, cpu-architecture, intel, privileges

I'm studying about Protection Ring system.

Can you give me some details about operation of this system in CPU level?

- Is it related to CPL?
- why they use especially "4" level? why not 2 or 3...(is it related to segmentation and paging?)

In addition, can you recommend some docs about Protection Ring?

(for now, I'm reading [Intel manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/processors/pentium4/sb/25366821.pdf))

Comment: *CPL* is the technical name, the *rings* are an analogy used by Intel to refer to the different CPL levels. Four because it's the first power of two bigger than 2 and Intel thought two levels were too few. CPL/Rings are related to segmentation and paging. Segments and selectors define the CPL of a piece of code, paging has rights based on it.

Comment: Semi-related: [CPU Privilege Rings: Why rings 1 and 2 aren't used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6710040) has a couple mentions of historical uses.  A microkernel might run some parts in ring 1, for example.

Comment: "Protection ring" is a generic computer architecture concept that is much older than x86.  See https://www.multicians.org/protection.html for a reference from 1971, linked from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) which would be a good starting point for you to read.  "Privilege levels" are the specific name that the 386 and successors used for their implementation of the concept of protection rings.