# Are ARM instructuons SWI and SVC exactly same thing?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, instruction-set

ARM assembly has SWI and SVC instructions for entering into 'supervisor mode'.

What confuses me is, why there are two of them? [Here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf) it is said that SVC was formerly SWI. Does it mean that basically they changed the mnemonic? Are they the same thing? Can I use them interchangeably? Does one of them exist before an architecture, and other after?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, SWI and SVC are same thing, it is just a name change. Previously, the SVC instruction was called SWI, Software Interrupt.

The opcode for SVC (and SWI) is partially user defined (bit 0-23 is user defined and is like a  parameter to SVC handler). Bits 24-27 are b1111 and these 4 bits makes CPU to realize that the opcode is SVC (or SWI).
see [ARM Information Center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0290g/ch02s08s13.html) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good UAL vs pre-UAL mnemonic table on [ARMv8](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/da/DDI0487D_a_armv8_arm.pdf) Appendix K6 "Legacy Instruction Syntax for AArch32 Instruction Sets"

One of the entries of that table is:

```
Pre-UAL syntax    UAL equivalent
SWI               SVC
```

which explicitly states that they are equivalent.

On GNU GAS, you can select the UAL syntax with `.syntax unified`.

From GCC, you can use the option `-masm-syntax-unified` for inline assembly, although it wasn't working in 8.2.0 due to a then fixed bug: [How to write .syntax unified UAL ARMv7 inline assembly in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078112/how-to-write-syntax-unified-ual-armv7-inline-assembly-in-gcc)

UAL vs pre-UAL also has further implications besides the names of certain instructions, e.g. the requirement for `#` or not in certain integer literals: [Is the hash required for immediate values in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652884/is-the-hash-required-for-immediate-values-in-arm-assembly/51987780#51987780)

Comment: and you can simply look at the documentation to see the instruction itself.