# How to know the linux kernel run either EL2 (non-secure) or EL3 (secure) mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64

Where can I check to know if the Linux kernel is running in non-secure (EL2) or secure (EL3) mode ?

How can I change this mode ?

I run on the ARMv8 64 bits.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The kernel runs at EL1...

Answer (score 5):

> Where can I check to know if the Linux kernel is running in non-secure (EL2) or secure (EL3) mode ?

I'm going to give a cheeky answer.

Adapt [what is the current execution mode/exception level, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787617/what-is-the-current-execution-mode-exception-level-etc/53445879#53445879) and hack your region of interest:

```
diff --git a/init/main.c b/init/main.c
index 18f8f0140fa0..840f886d17b3 100644
--- a/init/main.c
+++ b/init/main.c
@@ -533,6 +533,10 @@ asmlinkage __visible void __init start_kernel(void)
    char *command_line;
    char *after_dashes;

+   register u64 x0 __asm__ ("x0");
+   __asm__ ("mrs x0, CurrentEL;" : : : "%x0");
+   pr_info("EL = %llu\n", (unsigned long long)(x0 >> 2));
+
    set_task_stack_end_magic(&init_task);
    smp_setup_processor_id();
    debug_objects_early_init();
```

Output at the start of boot.

```
EL = 1
```

The default Linux kernel v4.19 boot logs also tell us that by default:

```
CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL1
```

> How can I change this mode?

Traditionally the kernel ran on EL1 only, and EL2 was left for a hypervisor like Xen, and EL3 for a bootloader like ARM Trusted Firmware.

However, with the introduction of the ARMv8.1 VHE extension, EL2 kernel became efficient and was added into Linux mainline: [What are Ring 0 and Ring 3 in the context of operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems/44483439#44483439) Not sure which config turns it on though, have a look.

EL3 I don't think there's anything mainline. There are some people trying to adapt kernel code to be the booloader as well, have a look e.g. at: https://github.com/kexecboot/kexecboot