# Difference of Perf At Kernel, User and System

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, perf

Can anyone give me better technical answer on difference between profiling using `perf` at `kernel` vs `user` vs `system` space?

The `perf` documentation [has details here](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Modifiers), but I am not sure if I collect data at user space, will that be more insightful than collecting at kernel space?

[image]

To give more details, what will be major difference between following `perf stat` command.

**System Wide**

```
perf stat -a --per-core -e instructions <application>
```

**User Space**

```
perf stat -a --per-core -e instructions:u <application>
```

**Kernel Space**

```
perf stat -a --per-core -e instructions:k <application>
```

**User and Kernel Space**

```
perf stat -a --per-core -e instructions:uk <application>
```

Comment: [Differences between User and Kernel modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311402/differences-between-user-and-kernel-modes) is a good place to start.

Comment: For root user (required to use `-a` system-wide) events by default are kernel+user space. User space will trigger events when user-space program code (some C/C++/Java/etc programs and libraries) is running and will not count when kernel code works. Kernel-space will profile only execution of OS kernel code (when Linux kernel works on requests from user code or when it does some periodic/hardware/driver jobs).